# calling a function from a function doesn't return value unless the main function is completed swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, function

Guys I need assistance on swift 4.0

i have a simple function that calls a json and fills those vars with values.

```
self.getDataFromServer()
```

after 'self.getDataFromServer()' this will fill in the arrays with retrieved data. This was working great on the previous version of swift (swift 3).

This is the code after the self.getDataFromServer() and getting index out of range, because data isn't populated (PS: This was working on swift 3.0)

```
var totalAmount = [String]()
var remainingAmount = [String]()

self.getDataFromServer()

let newTotal = Int(totalAmount[0])! + Int(remainingAmount[0])!
let newRemaining = String(newTotal)  


updateDailyData(newRemainingAmount: newRemaining, id: userID[0])
```

I'm getting error on 'newTotal' saying index out of range. Please Help.

I noticed that on swift 4, I'm facing this issue whenever i'm calling JSON.
The JSON Function is as below:

```
func getDataFromServer() {
    let dateOfToday = Date()
    let strDateOfToday = convertToString(myDate: dateOfToday)
    let postString = "ANYTHING HERE";
    let myUrl = URL(string: "ANYTHING HERE")
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    //Start the task
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        let values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        let  success = ((values.value(forKey: "success") as? [String])! as NSArray) as! [String]

        if (success[0] == "1")
        {
            self.totalAmount = ((values.value(forKey: "totalAmount") as? [String])! as NSArray) as! [String]
            self.remainingAmount = ((values.value(forKey: "remainingAmount") as? [String])! as NSArray) as! [String]

        }
    }
    //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your perfect working solution using **Closure**

**Swift 4**

```
        self.getDataFromServer { (arrTotalAmount, arrRemainingAmount) in
            if arrTotalAmount.count > 0, arrRemainingAmount.count > 0 {
                // Your code here
                let newTotal = Int(totalAmount[0])! + Int(remainingAmount[0])!
                let newRemaining = String(newTotal)
                updateDailyData(newRemainingAmount: newRemaining, id: userID[0])
            }
        }

        func getDataFromServer(completion: @escaping (_ arrTotalAmount: [String], _ arrRemainingAmount: [String]) -> Void) {
            let dateOfToday = Date()
            let strDateOfToday = convertToString(myDate: dateOfToday)
            let postString = "ANYTHING HERE";
            let myUrl = URL(string: "ANYTHING HERE")
            var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
            //Start the task
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?,      response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

                if error != nil
                {
                    print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }
                let values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

                let  success = ((values.value(forKey: "success") as? [String])! as NSArray) as! [String]

                if (success[0] == "1")
                {
                    let totalAmount = ((values.value(forKey: "totalAmount") as? [String])! as NSArray) as! [String]
                    let remaininAmount = ((values.value(forKey: "remainingAmount") as? [String])! as NSArray) as! [String]

                    completion(totalAmount, remaininAmount)
                }
            }
            //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
            task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: Mate, Thank you for the reply! I appreciate it, and honestly I haven't tried it as the below solution is fast to use and work on. But I'm facing an unlimited looping through the function that never stops, Even tried to return, but still.

Comment: It will work if you can call this closure method using DispatchQueue.global(), Your unlimited loop will not interrupt any single process.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really imagine this working in Swift 3, since the effects of your `getDataFromServer` function are asynchronous. More precisely, the function returns before the code inside the `dataTask` is executed.

Try something like this to execute code on the caller side after the dataTask has succeeded:

```
func getDataFromServer(onDone: () -> Void) {
    ...
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { ... in
        ...
        onDone()
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And to call it:

```
var totalAmount = [String]()
var remainingAmount = [String]()

self.getDataFromServer {

    let newTotal = Int(totalAmount[0])! + Int(remainingAmount[0])!
    let newRemaining = String(newTotal)

    updateDailyData(newRemainingAmount: newRemaining, id: userID[0])
}
```

Comment: Man, your solutions works like a charm, but the weird part is that it's keep loading the ViewDidLoad() as that code is in there, or anywhere i call that function getDataFromServer { CODE }, it goes into unlimited loop. Any advise?